# unexpected EOF while parsing のエラーを直したい

Tags: python, network, numpy, pytorch

現在，[bindnet][1] というライブラリーを用いてRecurrent Spiking Neural netを作成しており，トレーニングデータ（npzファイル）をload（xとyの値）してシミュレーションを行いたいのですが，enumerate関数で取り出そうとすると，"unexpected EOF while parsing" というエラーが表示されます．npzファイルの要素の取り出し方に問題があるのでしょうか？どなたか，ご教示の程よろしくお願い致します．
bindesnetというライブラリーを使用しています．
[1] https://bindsnet-docs.readthedocs.io/bindsnet.analysis.html

トレーニングデータはGitHubのコードを参考にしています[2]．リンクのtrain_set.npzです．このgitのコードをbindsnetを使ってrecurrent spiking neural netに変換しようとしています．
train_set.npzからxとyの値を取り出したいです．
[2] https://github.com/exelban/myo-armband-nn

**tain_set.npzに関連するコード（includeディレクトリのdata.py)**

```
import numpy as np
def get_data_set(name="train"):
x = None
y = None
if name is "train":
    npzfile = np.load("C:/Users/namae/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/myo-armband-nn-master/data/train_set.npz")
    #("C:/Users/namae/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/myo-armband-nn-master/data/train_set.npz")
    #("./data/train_set.npz")
    x = npzfile['x']
    y = npzfile['y']
elif name is "test":
    npzfile = np.load("./data_set/test_set.npz")
    #("C:/Users/namae/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/myo-armband-nn-master/data/train_set.npz")
    #("./data_set/test_set.npz")
    x = npzfile['x']
    y = npzfile['y']
  return x, y
```

エラーが出るコード部分（erumerateからrangeに変えたり，numpyの要素名を入れたりしましたがが．うまくいかなかったです）おそらくエラーは最後の行だと思います
参考にしているコード
　
**エラー文**

```
C:\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/namae/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/bindsnet-
  master/bindsnet/preRSNN.py 


File "C:/Users/namae/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/bindsnet master/bindsnet/preRSNN.py", line 84 SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

**エラー箇所**

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(get_data_set("train")):
```

次に現在，実装しているコードを示します．エラー箇所は最後の分です．

```
import torch
from bindsnet.network import Network
from bindsnet.network.nodes import Input, LIFNodes
from bindsnet.network.topology import Connection
from bindsnet.network.monitors import Monitor
from bindsnet.analysis.plotting import plot_spikes, plot_voltages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from include.model import model
from include.data import get_data_set
import numpy as np 
x, y, output, global_step, y_pred_cls = model(6)
test_x, test_y = get_data_set()
test_l = ["Relax", "Ok", "Fist", "Like", "Rock", "Spock"]
train_x, train_y = get_data_set()
time = 500
network = Network()
source_layer = Input(n=100, sum_input=True)
target_layer = LIFNodes(n=1000, sum_input=True)
network.add_layer(
    layer=source_layer, name='A'
)
network.add_layer(
    layer=target_layer, name='B'
)
foward_connection = Connection(
source=source_layer,
target=target_layer,
w= 0.05 + 0.1*torch.randn(source_layer.n, target_layer.n),
) 
network.add_connection(
    connection=foward_connection, source='A', target='B'
) 
recurrent_connection = Connection(
   source=source_layer,
   target=target_layer,
    w=0.025*(torch.eye(target_layer.n) - 1),
)
network.add_connection(
   connection=recurrent_connection, source="B", target="B")  
source_monitor = Monitor(
   obj=source_layer,
   state_vars=("s",), 
   time=time, )
target_monitor = Monitor(
   obj=target_layer,
   state_vars=("s","v"), # スパイクと電圧の記録
   time=time,)
network.add_monitor(monitor=source_monitor, name="A")
network.add_monitor(monitor=target_monitor, name="B")
for l in network.layers:# 状態変数のmonitor
    m = Monitor(network.layers[l], state_vars=['s'], time=time)
    network.add_monitor(m, name=l)
x, y = get_data_set("C:/Users/namae/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/myo-armband-nn- 
                    master/data/train_set.npz")
grads = {}
lr, lr_decay = 1e-2, 0.95
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss() # 誤差計算
spike_ims, spike_axes, weights_im = None, None, None 
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(get_data_set("train")):
```

Comment: プログラムのどの箇所で、どんなエラーメッセージが出るのですか？
エラーメッセージの全文を質問に追加すると、回答がくるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

```py
get_data_set("C:/Users/namae/Desktop/myo-python-1.0.4/myo-armband-nn-master/data/train_set.npz")
```

ではなく、

```py
get_data_set("train")
```

だと思います。[ソースコード](https://github.com/exelban/myo-armband-nn/blob/master/include/data.py)を見ると、データセット・ファイルのパスではなく文字列の`"train"`か`"test"`を期待していますね。